# Cellpadding alternative in <td> for email template

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I can use padding because many client didn't support it, either external css.

What I want is no cellpadding for the img but padding for the image description

```
 <table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></td>

        <td>1) pic description</td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7MzfR/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<td style="padding:0;"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></td>
```

Here's your example updated: http://jsfiddle.net/7MzfR/1/

Just use inline CSS if you can't use an external CSS document.

Answer (score 1):

For html email, you need to include `display:block;` on your image if you want to avoid a space appearing below it in the cell. This is what your code should look like for maximum compatibility with all major email clients:

```
<table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="100">
      <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
    </td>
    <td width="200" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="padding:10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
      Image Description
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There is a bunch of 'extra stuff' in the code - all of it is needed for consistency in html email. I'd also suggest, if you want a 1px border, to instead nest your table. It looks like a lot of wasted code, but offers more consistency and also looks better:

```
<table width="302" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#000000">
  <tr>
    <td height="102" valign="middle" align="center">
      <table width="300" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="100">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" width="100" height="100" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
          </td>
          <td width="200" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" style="padding:10px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
            Image Description
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try "inline style":

```
 <table border="1" >
<tr>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></td>

    <td style="padding:10px;">1) pic description</td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, place an inline styled span around the description, but within the table data. You could also inline style the table data, but it is optimal to use a span as follows:

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/></td>

        <td><span style="margin: 5px;">1) pic description</span></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```